# In Rails 6, how do I add "protocol" into my db configs?

Tags: mysql, database, configuration, localhost, ruby-on-rails-6

I have my MySql 5.7 db running on a virtual server, whose port 3306 is forwarded to my local . I can connect using this

```
> mysql -h localhost --protocol=tcp -u mouser mydb_test -p
```

Which would fail if the params “--protocol=tcp” weren’t present.  As such, I’m trying to figure out how to add “protocol” into my database.yml config for Rails 6.  I discovered the below is not the way to do it

```
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  host: localhost
  database: mydb_test
  pool: 5
  username: mouser
  password: mypass
  protocol: tcp
  variables:
    sql_mode: NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Since I get connection errors when attempting to connect to the db.